# Access type declaration effect on deallocation

Tags: ada

Is the memory freed the same way after the declare block (and before the end of the procedure of course) in both cases:

```
procedure allocation is 
    type T_Integer_Access is access Integer;
begin
    declare
        P : T_Integer_Access;
    begin
        P := new Integer'(5);
    end;
end;

procedure allocation is 
begin
    declare
        type T_Integer_Access is access Integer;
        P : T_Integer_Access;
    begin
        P := new Integer'(5);
    end;
end;
```

Put another way, has the access type declaration an effect on memory deallocation?

Comment: It should be noted that **only** provided that finalization of objects frees memory, there can be a difference at all.  Deallocation of `new`-ed memory is not automatic for standard memory pools. Hence, you'd override `Finalize` to have that affect.

Comment: @B98, what `Finalize` do you mean?

Comment: I was thinking ahead, sloppily presuming the idiom of a type-to-be, derived from `Ada.Finalization.Controlled`, in place of `Integer`. The derived type's  `Finalize` would then be overridden to perform storage management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a good chance that the storage pool (memory arena) from which objects of type `T_Integer_Access` is allocated won’t be freed ever, since you haven’t defined your own storage pool; [AARM 13.11](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-13-11.html) says at (2.a)

> By default, the implementation might choose to have a single global storage pool, which is used (by default) by all access types, which might mean that storage is reclaimed automatically only upon partition completion. Alternatively, it might choose to create a new pool at each accessibility level, which might mean that storage is reclaimed for an access type when leaving the appropriate scope. Other schemes are possible.

-- in other words, it’s not specified by the language.

I think it’s very unusual to define access-to-object types other than at library level. I’ve never done it, so I don’t know what compilers actually do.

Update:

*valgrind* doesn’t run on macOS Sierra, so I tried on Debian jessie with GNAT GPL 2016; both your `Allocation`s definitely leak memory.

Storage pools are finalizable, so you could implement your own; or you might look at, for example, [Deepend](https://sourceforge.net/projects/deepend/).

Comment: Thanks, I also tried with GNAT and noted the memory leak in each case.

Answer (score 1):

While the *location* of the access type declaration in your example does not affect how memory is allocated or deallocated, the [chosen storage pool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42868718/230513) *may* do so. In either variation of `procedure allocation`, the execution of the enclosed [*block statement*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-6.html) proceeds as follows:

- The elaboration of its *declarative part* causes space to be allocated for a value of an access type; in this case, the value may be thought of conceptually as a pointer or reference to an `Integer`; the space for the value is typically allocated on an [execution stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).
- The execution of its *handled sequence of statements* causes the evaluation of an [allocator](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-8.html) that creates an object; in this case, the object is an `Integer` having the value `5`; the space for the object is typically allocated from a pool of memory supplied by the host operating system.

In either case, when the *block statement* concludes, the space allocated for the access value is reclaimed, but the space allocated for the `Integer` value may remain. See [*Ada Programming/Types/access*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/access) for additional details on reclaiming allocated storage.

Comment: But the storage pool /may/ be different in the two cases - effectively reclaiming the storage at different times.