# Extending a Variable's Lifetime

Tags: ada, gnat

To be fair, I cannot be entirely sure the title correctly describes the problem I am having, as it merely mirrors my current understanding of Ada as it is.

#### The Problem

I have a function:

```
function Make_Option (Title : String) return Access_Option is
    O : aliased Option := (
            Title_Len => Title'Length, 
            Title => Title);
begin -- Make_Option
    return O'Unrestricted_Access;
end Make_Option;
```

This function is supposed to create a new menu option for the user, that may in turn be inserted into a menu (one that you might see in a terminal-based environment). You are all probably sighing, as quite evidently, the `O` variable would be deallocated at the end of this function (from my current understanding). As such, using the `Unrestricted_Access` here is just plain stupidity, but it mirrors the result of what it is I am trying to accomplish (as this code indeed does compile successfully).

The `Access_Option` is defined as following:

```
type Access_Option is access all Option;
```

The idea is that with an access to the option, which in turn is a discriminated record, is that we can store it within an array-like structure (as the object itself varies in size).

Beyond doubt, it would be nice if we could instead use the `Access` attribute for this, as the compiler would then make sure the lifetime is long enough of the `O` variable we are referencing, but as the lifetime as a matter of fact only exists til the end of the `Make_Option` function, we are presented with the following:

> `non-local pointer cannot point to local object`

What I am then asking, is: how would I go about having a function to create `Access_Option`s for me? Is such a thing even possible, or am I doing it all wrong? To clarify, what I am trying to do is create a neat way for filling an array with references to discriminated records, that I can then dereference and use.

#### Thought Process

I personally have not tried too many things, more than think about solutions that may be plausible for the problem. And, frankly, rather than going crazy of working makeshift solutions, it would be nice to have a solution that works for large-scale applications too, without messing up the code base to bad.

Would you perhaps have some sort of object queue to handle it? Does Ada even deallocate resources automatically in the first place? Gah. I am confused.

Would it, in fact, be possible to somehow place the `O` variable outside of the scope for deallocation to then manually deallocate it later?

Comment: See also [*Access type declaration effect on deallocation*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42865200/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the example you show above a much simpler approach is to simply make an array of Unbounded_String:

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_Io;

procedure Str_Arrays is
   type Arr is array(1..10) of Unbounded_String;
   A : Arr;
begin
   for S of A loop
      S := To_Unbounded_String("Hello World!");
   end loop;
   for S of A loop
      Put_Line(To_String(S));
   end loop;
end Str_arrays;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try that.

There are two alternative options:

1) Use Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors instead of a plain array.

2) Give your record discriminant a default value.  Then you can store it in a plain array.

Comment: You might find `Ada.Containers.{Indefinite_,}{Hashed,Ordered}_Maps` useful, if options can be identified by e.g. enumerations or even strings.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be reinventing the bounded string. Alternatives include

- Using an instantiation of `Ada.Strings.Bounded.Generic_Bounded_Length`
- Using `Ada.Strings.Unbounded`
- Using an indefinite container (`Ada.Containers.Indefinite_*`) to hold type `String`